# How to debug this for loop that masks multiple rasters using a single shapefile?

Tags: for-loop, debugging, raster, mask, terra

I have a group of multiband rasters in a folder that I'd like to mask using a single shapefile. I'd like for the masked outputs (rasters) to go into a separate folder. I received help on here a while back in making a `for` loop to accomplish this. It worked great, but when I scaled it up (increased the number of polygons in the shapefile, and added more rasters) it didn't work as well anymore. To be specific, it will sometimes mask the rasters correctly, and sometimes not. I can't discern any pattern as i've run this code multiple times and each time the set of rasters that don't get masked are different.

Code so far:

```
library(terra)

#Creating directory to store inputs
ras_dir <- "/Users/USERID/rasters"
if (!file.exists(ras_dir)) {
  ras_dir <- dir.create("/Users/USERID/rasters")
}

#Creating directory to store outputs
mask_dir <- "/Users/USERID/masks"
if (!file.exists(mask_dir)) {
  mask_dir <- dir.create("/Users/USERID/masks")
}

#Twelve polygons in a shapefile
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
v <- v[c(1,4,5,7,9,12)] 

#10 rasters with 5 layers each. I'm not a good enough coder to programmatically write #these rasters to a directory and have them be different.
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
r <- rep(r, 5) * 1:5
names(r) <- paste0("band", 1:5)
writeRaster(r, "/Users/USERID/ras1.tif")
writeRaster(r, "/Users/USERID/ras2.tif")
writeRaster(r, "/Users/USERID/ras3.tif")
writeRaster(r, "/Users/USERID/ras4.tif")
writeRaster(r, "/Users/USERID/ras5.tif")
  
inf <- list.files("/Users/USERID/rasters", pattern="tif$", full.names=TRUE)
outf <- gsub("/Users/USERID/rasters", "/Users/USERID/masks", inf)

for (i in 1:length(inf)) {
  
  r <- rast(inf[i])
  c <- crop(r, v) #Here I crop first as it saves lots of time
  m <- mask(c, v, filename = outf[i], overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

To be clear, I know the code above runs correctly. For some reason it doesn't run with my longer dataset and I was wondering if anyone could shed light on any potential pitfalls of this type of `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

This looks good to me. One change I would make is to actually use the variables that represent the paths. That is, only hard-code them once, as I do below. But it would seem that in your actual implementation there is some mistake. It can help to use statements like `print(outf[i])` in the loop, and first try with a few files, and then more to see where the error first comes in.

```
library(terra)

ras_dir <- "rasters"
mask_dir <- "masks"
dir.create(ras_dir, FALSE, FALSE)
dir.create(mask_dir, FALSE, FALSE)

#Twelve polygons in a shapefile
v <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
v <- v[c(1,4,5,7,9,12)] 

#10 rasters with 5 layers each. 
r <- rast(system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra"))
r <- rep(r, 5) * 1:5
names(r) <- paste0("band", 1:5)
for (i in 1:5) {
    writeRaster(r * i, file.path(ras_dir, paste0("ras", i, ".tif")), overwrite=TRUE)
}

inf <- list.files(ras_dir, pattern="tif$", full.names=TRUE)
outf <- gsub(ras_dir, mask_dir, inf)
    
for (i in 1:length(inf)) {
  r <- rast(inf[i])
  c <- crop(r, v) 
  m <- mask(c, v, filename = outf[i], overwrite = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and helpful comments. The issue seems to have gone away after updating all packages and restarting R